# How to use global variable in class function bindvalue?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I want to use a global variable and use bindValue() to assign it to a place holder so the value can be inserted into a database. The function I'm using is below

```
public function insertComment() {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments ( name, email, commentText, articleID ) VALUES ( :name, :email, :commentText, :articleID )';
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":commentText", $this->commentText, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":articleID", $this->articleID, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
}
```

The reason I can't just make a public variable is because data is being posted from a form to it and using public or public static is an invalid syntax. The variables that I'm using are

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$commentText = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
```

Is what I want to do even possible or am I better off finding another way to assign the values so I can insert into a database?

Comment: What what what what what? "Using public is invalid syntax"? Care to tell me who told you that?

Comment: using `public $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';` is not a valid syntax is what i mean

Comment: Heard of `__construct()`?

Comment: yeah I used it in earlier in the code I just dont know how I would get the post variables into it

Comment: @PeeHaa's method is the correct method. Check his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by removing the creation of the database instance to outside the function, because by the looks of it you are opening and closing lots of database connections.

```
class Foo
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function insertComment($name, $email, $comment, $articlId) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments ( name, email, commentText, articleID ) VALUES ( :name, :email, :commentText, :articleID )';
        $st = $this->conn->prepare ( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":commentText", $commentText, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->bindValue( ":articleID", $articleID, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $st->execute();
    }
}

$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$foo = new Foo($conn);
$foo->insertComment($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['commentText'], $_POST['articleId']);
```

Or perhaps even better have some request object and use that to inject into the method.

Not sure what you mean by `global` variable though, because the request variables (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc) are superglobals meaning they are global by default. And can be accessed from anywhere (although it isn't really best practice).

Comment: Is there a way this would work without creating another `__construct` because I have already used it as an array and its throwing this error `Cannot use object of type PDO as array`

Comment: No, a class can only have one constructor. What you should do is add another argument like: `public function __construct($yourArray, $conn)`

Comment: how do I specify the argument in the construct now?

Comment: Like in my previous comment. Or isn't that what you are asking?

Comment: what do I put in the construct function because I put `$conn`in as as extra arguement as you suggest and I'm not getting this error `Missing argument 2 for Comment::__construct()`

Comment: You have to call the now with `$foo = new Foo($yourArray, $conn)`.